# How to solve matrix equation in matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have H and G and Am matrix. All are 4x4. Both H and G are symmetrical and next equation:
      H*Am+Am*H=-G. How can I solve this in matlab?
      Am I right about this:
      2H*Am=-G and 2Am*H=-G?

But when I use H=linsolve(Am,-G/2) gives me nonsymmetrical matrix

```
H=linsolve(Am,-G/2)
```

Comment: Can you provide values of H, G and Am? Also AxB is not equal BxA

Comment: You should note that matrix multiplication is **not** commutative: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property#Noncommutative_operations_in_mathematics.  `AB` is usually **not** the same as `BA`, so combining the terms above like you see in your post is not valid matrix mathematics.  Also using `linsolve` assumes that your problem is of the form `AX = B`.  `X` is implicitly a `N x 1` matrix.  If you're saying that `H` is 4 x 4, then you can't use `linsolve`.  Please update your problem to include more information. This is unsolvable in its current state.

Comment: It's a special kind of equation and called Lyapunov' equation.(see Control System). You can solve it use function lyap() in matlab. See more in help.

Comment: Have you resolved your problem? This question is strange since you seem to have found an answer (use lyap) but in the original post you use linsolve and suggest that you don't really understand the required linear algebra manipulations?

Comment: You may want to check [wikipedia lyapunov](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_equation) as well unless you want to use the matlab function `lyap()` which would be recommended.

Comment: I think I found a bug in function lyap of matlab.

Comment: #patrik at least matlab and scilab show different results. And I tend to think  that scilab is right

Answer (score 2):

Here is a similar problem . You can see

[Find the all elements of unknown matrix in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72536151/find-the-all-elements-of-unknown-matrix-in-matlab)

You can use `equationToMatrix` in matlab to solve a set of equations.

Comment: Good find. This solves the problem. Maybe include a few lines that show how to use equationToMatrix and address the part of the question where OP asks if is correct that "2HAm=-G and 2AmH=-G" to answer the question completely. You might also flag it as duplicate if you find the question to be close enough to the one you cite

Comment: The problem with the OP asking "2HAm = -G or AmH = -G". is that is is taking AmH = HAm which is not usually the case . Matrix multiplication is not commutative i,e AB ~! BA . unless A = B which I don't think is the case here .

Answer (score 0):

use syms if variable Y is not known

for example:

```
 syms y
 solve(2*y-4==0)
```

---

```
 ans= 2
```

to specify the matrix eq you should define the size of y:

```
 y=sym('y',[2,1]);
 A=[1 0;0 1];
 c=[1;2];
 z=[0;0];
 B=solve(A*y-c==z);
```

B is a structure which stores value of y1 and y2

```
 B.y1
 ans= 
      1
```

---

for this question:

```
H=sym('H',[4,4]);
B=solve(H*Am+Am*H==G)
B.H11 % to retrieve H11
```